# PHPEXCEL get formatted date as is visible in excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to import a excel file using PhpExcel lib
for all other fields the `getValue()` function works but when it encounters a field with format date as set in ms-excel2013
the date field in exel file is in format d-m-Y like `16-11-2014`
but when I try to import it's value the `getValue()` returns `11-16-14` which when passed to `strtotime` further `returns false` in turn causing the `date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date))` to return `1970-01-01`.

I searched whole of web and stackoverflow but none solution fixed my problem.
In excel file i see the date as `16-11-2014` and want it to be imported as is.

Here's the code

```
protected function importExcel($filePath) {
    $excelData = array();
    if ($filePath) {
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filePath);
        $objPHPExcel->setReadDataOnly(true);
        foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
            $worksheetTitle = $worksheet->getTitle();
            $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
            $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
            $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
            $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
            $data = array();
            for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
                $values = array();
                for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
                    $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                    if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell))
                        throw new Exception("is date time"); // just a check
                    $val = $cell->getValue();
                    if (isset($val) && $val)
                        $data[$row][$col] = $val;
                }
            }
            $excelData[$worksheetTitle] = $data;
        }
        return $excelData;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: @miken32 No, it's not the duplicate as I checked entire web before posting the question and answer too. Kindly read the question and answers mentioned over here, you'll come to know the difference. As Mark Baker(coordinator PhpExcel lib) himself tried helping me in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the solution:

Method *_formatAsDate* in the file *PHPExcel/Style/NumberFormat.php*

[image: The method _formatAsDate in NumberFormat.php]

if the date is like `16/11/2014`, when passed to `strtotime` will result in `false` as the date is supposed to be in format `m/d/Y` by `strtotime`. So if you change the format to `m/d/Y` if it's `d/m/Y` then the solution will always be correct.

#### Earlier:

1. 16/11/2014==1970-01-01 (Row: 1)
2. 16/11/2014==1970-01-01 (Row: 2)
3. 23/12/2014==1970-01-01 (Row: 3).

#### Now:

1. 11/16/2014==2014-11-16 (Row: 1)
2. 11/16/2014==2014-11-16 (Row: 2)
3. 12/23/2014==2014-12-23 (Row: 3)

Code is still the same and simple to import the file:

```
protected function importExcel($filePath) {
    $excelData = array();
    if ($filePath) {
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filePath);
        foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
            $worksheetTitle = $worksheet->getTitle();
            $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
            $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
            $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
            $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
            $data = array();
            for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
                $values = array();
                for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
                    $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                    $val = $cell->getValue();
                    if (isset($val) && $val)
                        $data[$row][$col] = $val;
                }
            }
            $excelData[$worksheetTitle] = $data;
        }
        return $excelData;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: thanks #mark baker for letting me know the file and function via your last commit. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 9):

A `getValue()` call on a field containing a date should return a value like `41959.00` if that field really does contain an MS Excel date value.... that is, an MS Excel serialized datetime stamp based on the number of days since 1st January 1900 (or 1st January 1904 if the file was created using the Mac version of MS Excel)

To get a formatted date string, you need to call `getFormattedValue()` instead; and PHPExcel then uses the number format mask for that cell to format the date according to that mask.

To identify if a cell contains an MS serialized datetime stamp, you can use a call to `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime()` first.

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    echo 'Worksheet - ' , $worksheet->getTitle() , EOL;

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        echo '    Row number - ' , $row->getRowIndex() , EOL;

        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            if (!is_null($cell)) {
                echo '        Cell - ' , $cell->getCoordinate() , ' - ';
                if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
                    echo $cell->getFormattedValue() , EOL;
                } else {
                    echo $cell->getValue() , EOL;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Rather than returning a formatted data value, you can also ask PHPExcel to return the date as a Unix timestamp, or as a PHP DateTime object instead; and then you'll be able to format it however you want using PHP's built-in date functions or DateTime methods.

```
if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
    $unixTimeStamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cell->getValue());
    echo date('d-M-Y H:i:s', $unixTimeStamp), PHP_EOL;
}
```

or

```
if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
    $dateTimeObject = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($cell->getValue());
    echo $dateTimeObject->format('d-M-Y H:i:s'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell) is returning false
so the above suggestion didn't work
neither the getFormattedValue(); the file was created using windows and MS-Excel 2013

Comment: You didn't load the file using `setReadDataOnly(true)` did you?

Comment: i did `$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filePath);
            $objPHPExcel->setReadDataOnly(true);`

Comment: I posted the code above, please see and suggest as the exception is not thrown @ `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)`

Comment: Comment out the line `$objPHPExcel->setReadDataOnly(true);`.... because this line tells PHPExcel to only load raw data, and to ignore any style information such as date masks, so it's impossible to identify if a cell is a date or not if you use this

Comment: the above suggestion also didn't worked out

Comment: Then I'd guess you don't actually have dates in your spreadsheet, but have strings; and the fact that `getValue()` doesn't return a value like `41959.00` but returns `11-16-14` instead seems to confirm that.... but as I can't see your spreadsheet, you'd have to check that yourself

Comment: i have dates in my excel sheet. the cell format in the sheet is date : d-m-Y

Comment: If you have MS Excel dates in the spreadsheet, then changing a cell that contains one of those dates to format it as `number` will show a number like `41959.00`.... does it?

Comment: yes it does----
But when the `PHPEXCEL` library calls the `Excel2007`, it explicitly typecasts the value to string. `PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007` line no 847 - the `switch` calls the `default` case where the `if` condition does `$value = self::_castToString($c);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84168/discussion-between-ashwani-shukla-and-mark-baker).

Comment: And then there is a check in lines 910-915 of that file: `// Check for numeric values
          if (is_numeric($value) && $cellDataType != 's') {
           if ($value == (int)$value) $value = (int)$value;
           elseif ($value == (float)$value) $value = (float)$value;
           elseif ($value == (double)$value) $value = (double)$value;
          }` which will cast numbers to integer or float as appropriate

Comment: but since the $value is converted into string on line 897
so it won't satify the condition and will not be converted into number or float. As This sets the PHPExcel_Cell->_value to string, as a setValue is called in PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007 line no. 926

Comment: It will be converted to a float or int if it __is_numeric()__: `if (is_numeric($value) && $cellDataType != 's')`.... if it's not a numeric, then it shouldn't be cast to int or float

Comment: thanks #mark baker , i value your suggestions but they aren't helping out. If you have a solution then please post. Or if you know that from where does the `PHPEXCEL` lib converts the date from `d-m-Y` || `timestamp` to `m-d-y` then pls tell me the file and line and I'll modify it accordingly to solve the purpose.

Comment: I don't have a solution.... I want to know what's so different about your spreadsheet that means the existing code doesn't work.... if I can't identify that difference, and there is a bug in PHPExcel, then I'm not going to be able to fix it.... the existing code works perfectly correctly for dates in every test that I have, so I can't understand why it doesn't work for your dates

Comment: Even if PHPExcel was reading your dates as strings, it should not be changing those strings in any way.... if `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell))` returns a false, then there isn't a number mask associated with that cell that can identify it as a date; that's also something that I can't understand

Comment: Is there any way that you can email me the file to run some tests, or is it confidential information?

Comment: I have attached a link to the file in the question above. it will be valid for 2 days only. Kindly lemme know if you find a solution. Mail me at ashwanishukla@live.com

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the file that you provided, looking at your date issue.

The format that you're using for those dates in your spreadsheet is a locale-aware date format, flagged by MS Excel with an asterisk (*) if you look at the cell format

This means (quoting from Excel's notes on the format mask display):

> Date formats that begin with an asterisk (*) respond to changes in regional date and time settings that are specified for the Operating System.

Because PHPExcel is not locale-aware, but does recognise the format mask as a date value, it uses a generic formatting.

---

Running the following code

```
var_dump($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I5')->getValue());
var_dump(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I5')));
var_dump($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I5')->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode());
var_dump($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I5')->getFormattedValue());
```

gives

```
float(42062)
bool(true)
string(8) "mm-dd-yy"
string(8) "02-27-15"
```

So (as long as you've removed that `setReadDataOnly(true)` call from the Reader, call from the Reader, you can still identify date cells as dates, and format them manually, overriding the default locale-formatting

```
if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I5'))) {
    $dateTimeObject = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I5')->getValue());
    echo $dateTimeObject->format('d-m-Y'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: though dates in the spreadsheet is a locale-aware date format, flagged by MS Excel with an asterisk (*) if we look at the cell format but the format is that of `d-m-Y` which is understood by PHP that's why is transforming the date to `m-d-y` but since it uses the same separator as in date in excel file therefore it creates a problem, as `m-d-y` as provided by `PHPEXCEL` is understood by php `strtotime` function as `d-m-y` and since `02-27-15` is not a valid `d-m-y` format (as month cannot be greater than 12) therefore the `strtotime` function `return false` so the `date` return `1970-01-01`.

Comment: thanks #mark baker , I value your suggestions but they aren't helping out. I found an alternate and converted the column to `m-d-Y` and now the things are fine but it's an alternate and not a solution. So, If you have a solution then please post. Or if you know that from where does the `PHPEXCEL` lib converts the date from `d-m-Y` || `timestamp` to `m-d-y` then pls tell me the file and line and I'll modify it accordingly to solve the purpose. As it's a bug in `PHPEXCEL` lib which I cannnot entertain.

Comment: This is not a __bug__ in PHPExcel, simply the fact that PHPExcel is not aware of your locale, and therefore cannot convert a date to a format that it doesn't know..... the code that I've provided should work correctly if you've implemented it as I showed above.... where you specify exactly what format you wish to apply when converting the MS Serialized timestamp values to a formatted string

Comment: Nor is it anything to do with `/` or `-`. The MS Excel serialized date contains neither of those characters because it's a float, a unix timestamp contains neither of those characters because it's an integer, nor does a PHP DateTime object.... only the formatted end result as a string contains either of those characters

Comment: #mark baker : I have changed the cell format of date to Indian date format. Now You will not see the `* ` in cell format. But still I am facing the same problem. The issue is actually what I told you in the above comment. I have added the modified file in the link above. Please download the file and check and then tell me what actually the problem is.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this "bug" with any non-locale date format..... I've even completely rewritten the date formatting code (albeit for other reasons) and pushed that to the 1.8 branch on github last night..... but f I can't replicate any problem, it's extremely difficult to know if it's fixed or not

Comment: #mark try using the English(UK) => d-m-Y format in the sheet. Still the same error.

Comment: what i saw:
Errors in file
1 16/11/2014==1970-01-01 (Row: 1)
2 16/11/2014==1970-01-01 (Row: 2)
3 23/12/2014==1970-01-01 (Row: 3)
4 27/02/2015==1970-01-01 (Row: 4)
5 27/02/2015==1970-01-01 (Row: 5)
6 18/11/2014==1970-01-01 (Row: 6)
7 31/01/2015==1970-01-01 (Row: 7)
8 30/11/2014==1970-01-01 (Row: 8)
9 29/12/2014==1970-01-01 (Row: 9)
10 20/02/2015==1970-01-01 (Row: 10)
11 23/02/2015==1970-01-01 (Row: 11)
12 20/11/2014==1970-01-01 (Row: 12)
13 10/01/2015==2015-10-01 (Row: 13)
14 12/02/2015==2015-12-02 (Row: 14)

Comment: still there's the prob. after implementing your latest code.